# Calculate polygon points from image

Tags: c#, opengl

I'm new to OpenGL, so please excuse my brevity and/or lack of technical knowledge of the subject.

I need some help with rendering a polygon on an OpenGL canvas (using C# w/ Tao). I understand that I will need to tessellate the polygon points so it'll draw correctly, but technicality aside, what's the best method to get usable XY points from the image below so I can draw the polygon shape?

[image]

Comment: You can render it as an image, the image you have as a texture-map on a single square (two triangles). Of design the polygon & triangles yourself with a pencil and graph paper. Or programmatically trace the outline (with some rules about when to make stair-steps versus diagonals), and find an algorithm for "triangulation".

Comment: I would suggest trying [Marching Squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) to generate polygons from a binary image.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to vectorize the polygon, one way is to first find all the edges by tracing along boundaries between adjacent differing pixels, then perform a relaxation/simplification step that optimizes the resulting polygon by merging connecting segments, using something like [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)

An example method, although they use a different policy for curve simplification that generates Bezier splines, is the algorithm detailed at [Potrace: a polygon-based tracing algorithm](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/potrace.pdf). This seems to be the algorithm that Inkscape uses.

Usually, however, in games we'd render a picture such as your example plane image as a raster texture.

If you want the advantages of vectors, you could consider generating a distance field representation of the image, which allows for low-resolution raster storage of a vector texture

[Improved Alpha-Tested Magnification for Vector Textures and Special Effects](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/valve/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf)