# How to generate mesh for any shape?

Tags: unity, mesh

I have shape stored in sprite. Shape is stored as white color. I want to generate mesh for given shape. Maybe just like sprite collider do. What algorithm I have to choose? Are there any libs for Unity that can do that?

Comment: This sounds like a simple scan over the pixels till you find a white pixel, then a walk around the perimeter to build the outer chain of vertices of your polygon, then a standard triangulation algorithm to break that polygon into triangles. Each of these steps is extensively documented in standard computer science literature and tutorials. Which step exactly do you need help with?

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for the tip. I think that I will be able to deal with the "walk around the perimeter". But can you provide simple algorithm to triangulate the polygon?

Comment: Don't forget to [search for existing Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/88056/39518). For topics like polygon triangulation, [just searching Wikipedia will suffice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found easy solution.

I have used [Unity-SpriteAssist](https://github.com/sr4dev/Unity-SpriteAssist) library.

This method generates new mesh data according to the initial parameters:

```
maskSprite.GetVertexAndTriangle3D(spriteConfigData, out Vector3[] vertices2D, out int[] triangles2D, MeshRenderType.Opaque);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find the Marching Squares algorithm handy.

This is a C++ implementation, which shouldn't be too hard to port to C#:

https://github.com/sjhalayka/Marching-Squares

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares